# Office Communicator Auto Accept Calls with C# API

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-communicator

Is there a way to automatically accept calls programmed with the C# Api when someone calls 'me' to start a video call?

Starting a video call with the API is easy:

```
var contactArray = new ArrayList();
contactArray.Add("abc@def.local");
object[] sipUris = new object[contactArray.Count];
int currentObject = 0;
foreach (object contactObject in contactArray)
{
    sipUris[currentObject] = contactObject;
    currentObject++;
}
var communicator = new Messenger();
communicator.OnIMWindowCreated += new DMessengerEvents_OnIMWindowCreatedEventHandler(communicator_OnIMWindowCreated);
IMessengerAdvanced msgrAdv = communicator as CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerAdvanced;
if (msgrAdv != null)
{
    try
    {
        object obj = msgrAdv.StartConversation(CommunicatorAPI.CONVERSATION_TYPE.CONVERSATION_TYPE_VIDEO, sipUris, null, "Conference Wall CZ - Conversation", "1", null);
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But on the other side i want to automatically accept this call....

Comment: Friend, I have the same doubt. You got something?

Comment: I did not find a solution for this problem yet. Hopefully someone has the solution, and will answer my question.

Comment: did you get around that problem? I will try use some Windows API. http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx

Comment: I dit not find a solution yet. I've taken a brief look at the link you send, but i'm not sure how to use this link to get around my problem. Can you maybe supply me with an example? Or a hint in the right direction how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with OC so far as I've found, presumably for security reasons. What I ended up doing was having the remote bot call me then I answer. So I chat "start video" to a messenger account that I've got a service listening to. That service calls me, then I answer it on my side manually.